# Example of change management approach in PMBOK

Tags: pmbok

I'm reading the book OnHome - A Project Manager book of Forms, which provide forms of document in PMBOK. But I'm stuck at understanding this part called Change management approach. It said "Describe the degree of change control and how change control will integrate with other aspects of project management.". So my question is what is an example of Change management approach in this context?

Comment: Looks like you've got multiple questions here. Might want to focus on one question per Question to avoid being closed as too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a PMP and have trained other project managers. I think this refers to a scenario where any requested change to the project plan must go through a formal approval process. Instead, a request to a change in scope (for example) could just be negotiated by the project sponsor; the project team has to accept it; and the sponsor is fine with the project manager's resulting changes to the project plan.

In a more formal process, there could be a Change Board of upper managers. The scope change is entered into a Change Request that the board accepts, rejects, or sends back for revision. If it accepts the changes, the board might also have the power to approve the changes to the project plan that result.

Each of these examples are forms of change management. The question seems to ask how the change process you set up would apply to scope management, schedule changes, budget changes, people management, etc.

Note that all of this goes away with fully Agile approaches. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your clarification